# dojox/mvc/getStateful support hierarchy

Tags: dojo

Here is a dojo sandbox showing my intended use of getStateful(): http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/7917e/1

It seems that getStateful() initially creates watchCallbacks for each level of the model, but when called again in the button click getStateful() creates the watchCallbacks at the root level but not the nested level of my model.

I've looked at newStatefulModel also, but the documentation indicates that getStateful is the successor, and should be used.

If there are options I should pass to getStateful() to make this happen, how come it seemed to work initially?

EDIT: It looks like my problem is not with the getStateful method, but with the ModelRefController.set method, or more specifically the _Controller.set method.

I'm throwing a hierarchy at the ModelRefController, and it's accepting the entire hierarchy as the new "model" value, but only defining watchCallbacks on the "model" (root).

I would have expected it to accept the provided object and perform the wiring at all levels within the passed in value, instead of having to set each individual object in the hierarchy into the ModelRefController.

I may be going about it the wrong way, but I would like to have a template that knows all of the specifics about the fields it is capable of displaying, and have the widget (controller) concerned only with those properties on the model that drive logic in the widget (controller).

I'm generating the UI from a page definition, and at runtime providing additional decoration in the UI regarding the meta data of the model properties.  I can easily generate the necessary calls to the ModelRefController to sync its contents with new data received from the backend, just didn't think it would require so much code.

Here's another Dojo sandbox: http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/e6946/0

The model's initial values are "Foo".  And when new data is pushed into the model containing "Bar", it rebinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new example in http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/ef38d/1 confirms that the application needs the "view model", which is the model the UI components looks at, to contain both of the two models to make it work.

Also, the update in the original question implies that there was an expectation for [dojox/mvc/ModelRefController](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/ModelRefController.html) to support the notion of "recursive path watch", though it does not. I also have an impression that [dojox/mvc/at](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/at.html) supporting recursive path watch would the the most thing that would help http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/ef38d/1 as well as http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/e6946/0, though it's not supported. The impression is especially from http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/ef38d/1 that seems to have wanted to watch for `dataModel.model.nextLevel.title` path (though the code does not).

Though the implementation may not be something desirable, the best way I can think of to make the sample work is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dojo/Stateful tree with dojox/mvc/getStateful</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: 0, async: 1, mvc: {debugBindings: 1}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/declare",
                "dojo/Stateful",
                "dojo/parser",
                "dijit/Destroyable",
                "dojox/mvc/getStateful",
                "dojox/mvc/parserExtension",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function (declare, Stateful, parser, Destroyable, getStateful) {
                var watchPath = (function () {
                    function getPathComps(path) {
                        return path === "" ? [] : typeof path.splice !== "function" ? path.split(".") : path;
                    }
                    function getObjectPath(o, path) {
                        for (var comps = getPathComps(path), i = 0, l = comps.length; i < l; ++i) {
                            var comp = comps[i];
                            o = o == null ? o : o[comp];
                        }
                        return o;
                    }
                    return function (model, path, callback) {
                        if (model && typeof model.watch === "function") {
                            var comps = getPathComps(path),
                                prop = comps.shift(),
                                remainder = comps,
                                observer = {
                                    prop: prop,
                                    remainder: remainder,
                                    hProp: model.watch(prop, function (name, old, current) {
                                        var hasRemainder = observer.remainder.length > 0;
                                        if (old !== current) {
                                            if (observer.hRemainder) {
                                                observer.hRemainder.remove();
                                                observer.hRemainder = null;
                                            }
                                            observer.hRemainder = watchPath(model[prop], remainder.slice(), callback);
                                        }
                                        callback(hasRemainder ? getObjectPath(old, observer.remainder) : old,
                                            hasRemainder ? getObjectPath(current, observer.remainder) : current);
                                    }),
                                    hRemainder: watchPath(model[prop], remainder.slice(), callback),
                                    remove: function () {
                                        if (this.hRemainder) {
                                            this.hRemainder.remove();
                                            this.hRemainder = null;
                                        }
                                        if (this.hProp) {
                                            this.hProp.remove();
                                            this.hProp = null;
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                            return observer;
                        }
                    };
                })();

                var States = declare([Stateful, Destroyable], {
                        constructor: function (model) {
                            var self = this;
                        }
                    }),
                    App = declare(Stateful, {
                        firstDisabled: false,
                        secondDisabled: false,
                        model: null,
                        constructor: function () {
                            this.switchModel();
                        },
                        createModel: function () {
                            var model = getStateful({
                                    title: "Foo",
                                    nextLevel: {
                                        title: "Bar",
                                        nextLevel: {
                                            title: "Baz"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }),
                                states = new Stateful({
                                    firstDisabled: model.nextLevel.title === "Foo",
                                    secondDisabled: model.nextLevel.nextLevel.title === "Foo"
                                }),
                                h0 = watchPath(model, "nextLevel.title", function (old, current) {
                                    states.set("firstDisabled", current === "Foo");
                                }),
                                h1 = watchPath(model, "nextLevel.nextLevel.title", function (old, current) {
                                    states.set("secondDisabled", current === "Foo");
                                });
                            model.set("states", states);
                            model.nextLevel.set("states", states);
                            model.nextLevel.nextLevel.set("states", states);
                            model.destroy = function () {
                                if (h0) {
                                    h0.remove();
                                    h0 = null;
                                }
                                if (h1) {
                                    h1.remove();
                                    h1 = null;
                                }
                            }
                            return model;
                        },
                        switchModel: function () {
                            var oldModel = this.get("model"),
                                model = this.createModel();
                            if (oldModel) {
                                oldModel.destroy();
                            }
                            this.set("model", model);
                        }
                    });

                window.app = new App();
                parser.parse();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: at(app, 'model')">
            Selected:
            <span data-mvc-bindings="innerText: at('rel:', 'title')"></span>
            <select type="combo" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                    data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'title'), disabled: at('rel:states', 'firstDisabled')">
                <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
                <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
                <option value="Baz">Baz</option>
            </select>

            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: at('rel:', 'nextLevel')">
                Selected:
                <span data-mvc-bindings="innerText: at('rel:', 'title')"></span>
                <select type="combo" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                        data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'title'), disabled: at('rel:states', 'secondDisabled')">
                    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
                    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
                    <option value="Baz">Baz</option>
                </select>

                <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group" data-dojo-props="target: at('rel:', 'nextLevel')">
                    Selected:
                    <span data-mvc-bindings="innerText: at('rel:', 'title')"></span>
                    <select type="combo" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                            data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'title')">
                        <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
                        <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
                        <option value="Baz">Baz</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Switch model
            <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click" data-dojo-args="evt">
                app.switchModel();
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Best, -Akira

Comment: I was hoping that mvc/at would hold the answer, and that I would not have to get this intimate with Stateful.Watch.  I need to spend some time thinking about how to incorporate this into my solution, as parts of it are generated.  Thanks again for your prompt and comprehensive answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[dojox/mvc/getStateful](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/getStateful.html) creates a tree of [dojo/Stateful](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/Stateful.html) from the given object. `_watchCallbacks`, as the name suggests, is a private property of [dojo/Stateful](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/Stateful.html), which is set when one or more guys started watching for changes in its properties. Therefore `_watchCalbacks` not being there does not necessarily mean there is anything wrong with [dojox/mvc/getStateful](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/getStateful.html); Neither is it with http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/7917e/1.

What I see in http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/7917e/1 is this; As it tries to, watching for [dojo/Stateful](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/Stateful.html) hierarchy in UI side requires [dojox/mvc/Group](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/Group.html) (or something equivalent) with the right `target`. It needs to be done in every level of hierarchy, though. It means that if you have [dojox/mvc/Group](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/Group.html) watching for `model.nested`, you'll see `_watchCallbacks` set to `nested`. Here's an example how to declare hierarchcal watch in UI side (focus on [dojox/mvc/Group](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mvc/Group.html) usage):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dojo/Stateful tree with dojox/mvc/getStateful</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: 0, async: 1, mvc: {debugBindings: 1}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/declare",
                "dojo/Stateful",
                "dojo/parser",
                "dojox/mvc/getStateful",
                "dojox/mvc/parserExtension",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function (declare, Stateful, parser, getStateful) {
                var App = declare(Stateful, {
                    model: null,
                    constructor: function () {
                        this.switchModel();
                    },
                    createModel: function () {
                        return getStateful({
                            title: "Foo",
                            deeper: {
                                title: "Bar"
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    switchModel: function () {
                        this.set("model", this.createModel());
                    }
                });
                window.app = new App();
                parser.parse();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group"
            data-dojo-props="target: at(app, 'model')">
            Selected:
            <span data-mvc-bindings="innerText: at('rel:', 'title')"></span>
            <select type="combo" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'title')">
                <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
                <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
                <option value="Baz">Baz</option>
            </select>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group"
                data-dojo-props="target: at('rel:', 'deeper')">
                Selected:
                <span data-mvc-bindings="innerText: at('rel:', 'title')"></span>
                <select type="combo" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"
                    data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'title')">
                    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
                    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
                    <option value="Baz">Baz</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Switch model
            <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click" data-dojo-args="evt">
                app.switchModel();
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Best, -Akira

Comment: Hi Akira, Thanks for the reply.

I had gone down that route initially, wrapping all of my widgets in mvc/Group, to establish the context of the binding.  And it was working.

But, I needed to bind the widget to two contexts, one for value and another to derive other attributes like class, required, disabled, based on the evaluation of expressions defined by the page author and contained in another model.

This led me to establish the mvc/Group context at the page level and use 'rel:path.to.property' syntax in the at() declaration, which is now not working when switching the model.

Comment: I need more concrete example of the “two contexts” stuffs to provide how that can be achieved, but sounds that you’ll need to create a “view model” that contains both of the “two contexts”.

Comment: I used your example, included a state model, and cloned your UI with modifications to the dojo assertions as I would expect them to work with the 'rel:path.to.model' syntax.  [Two context example](http://dojo-sandbox.net/public/ef38d/1)